# Use popen and wait for the commands to run completly

Tags: c++, linux, popen

I need to run the following commands in C++.

```
cd ../ && tar cf files1.tar files && cp files1.tar files1cp.tar && tar xf files1cp.tar
```

popen method does the job:

```
FILE* pipe = popen("cd ../ && tar cf files1.tar files && cp files1.tar files1cp.tar && tar xf files1cp.tar", "r");

if (!pipe)
    throw("ERROR!");
char buffer[128];
string result = "";
while(!feof(pipe)) 
{
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
}
pclose(pipe);
```

According to the man page, The popen() function opens a process by creating a pipe, forking, and invoking the shell. Is there any way to disable the forking so that popen waits for the whole commands to be executed completely, and then relinquishes the control to the next line in the code.

Comment: No, but you can do exactly what `popen` does by creating your own child process, let it execute the programs you want, and in the parent process *wait* for the child process to end.

Comment: Also, don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will in most cases not work as expected. The reason is that the end-of-file flag will not be set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file. Instead to e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`. Or since you tagged your question C++ (even through there's almost no C++ code in your question) use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: There's no reason to use `popen()` for the command line shown; it won't write anything to standard output.  You might as well use `system()` instead of `popen()` and `pclose()`.  Note that `pclose()` waits for the command to complete before returning, but you don't call it until you get EOF on the stream, which also won't happen before the command completes.  Of course, `system()` waits for the command to complete too.